# Invalid Position in SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a query I am writing that examines an ID field and derives an ID number from that column based on several criteria. Now that I have its logic written, I want to run the query on each criteria to see if the logic is working. So, the last part of my query for doing so is as follows:

```
FROM TABLE1
WHERE SOURCE_SYSTEM_NM = 'XYZ' AND ((STRLEFT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID,4)) NOT IN ('23CC','21CC'))
LIMIT 10000
```

Essentially what I am trying to do here is tell it to return to me only items with SOURCE_SYSTEM_NM equal to 'XYZ', while eliminating any with a SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID not having the first 4 characters equal to '21CC' or '23CC'. I have a third criteria I want to filter on as well, which is that the first three characters must be '0CC'.

My problem when I run this is I get back an "Invalid Position" error. I removed one of the strings from the criteria, and it works. So, I decided to add the second in its own 'NOT IN...' clause with an AND between them, but that resulted in the same error.

If I had to guess, the `NOT IN ('21CC','23CC')` puts an AND between them and I think that must be the root of my issue. The criteria in my CASE statement derives the ID number with the following:

```
WHEN (M_CRF_CU_PRODUCT_ARRANGEMENT.SOURCE_SYSTEM_NM) IN ('XYZ') AND STRLEFT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID, 4) IN ('23CC','21CC') THEN STRRIGHT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID, LENGTH(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID)-4)
WHEN (M_CRF_CU_PRODUCT_ARRANGEMENT.SOURCE_SYSTEM_NM) IN ('XYZ') AND STRLEFT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID, 3) IN ('0CC') THEN STRRIGHT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID, LENGTH(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID)-3)
WHEN (M_CRF_CU_PRODUCT_ARRANGEMENT.SOURCE_SYSTEM_NM) IN ('XYZ') AND (STRLEFT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID, 4) NOT IN ('23CC','21CC') OR STRLEFT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID, 3) NOT IN ('0CC')) THEN (SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID)
```

So with that, I am just trying to check each criteria to make sure the ID derived/created is correct. I need to filter down to get results for that last WHEN statement above, but I keep getting that "Invalid Position" in my WHERE statement at the end. I am using Aginity to run this query and it's running against an IBM Netezza database. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was on this - when performing

```
STRRIGHT(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID, LENGTH(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID)-4)
```

There are some of those Arrangement IDs that do not have 4 characters, thus I was getting an "Invalid Position". I fixed this by updating this query to use substring() instead:

```
SUBSTRING(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID,5,LENGTH(SOURCE_ARRANGEMENT_ID))
```

This fixed my issue. Just wanted to post an answer in case others have this issue. It s not Netezza specific, this will react this way with any SQL variant.